# how to mark an active player in my application?

Tags: android

I want to make a game that allow user to challenge other player. The mechanic will be simple, you click on "Find opponent" button, application sends a request to webapi, gets random opponent and is starting a match. Now my problem is....how can I find an active opponent ? The one that application is running in foreground or background. I'm thinking about setting a flag in db for each player (is_active) and set it to true when app starts and set to false in `onDestroy` method.

What do you think about this solution ? Maybe there is something better ?